# How to show this inequality in algebra?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inequality, roots, quadratics

> If $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ , $\lambda_1<\lambda_2$ are roots of the equation $x^2-(3pq-p-q-2)x+(2p^2q^2-2p^2q-2pq^2+2pq-2p-2q+4)$ show that they satisfy
>
> > $\lambda_1<p(q-1)-1<pq-2<\lambda_2$ where $p,q$ are primes with $p<q$.

**I tried**:

One of $\lambda_1$ or $\lambda_2$ must be greater then $pq-2$.
Otherwise if both $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\le pq-2$ then $2(pq-2)\ge\lambda_1+\lambda_2=3pq-p-q-2$

$\implies 3pq-p-q-2\le 2pq-4\implies pq-p-q+2\le 0\implies pq+2\le p+q$ which is false.

Thus one of  $\lambda_1$ or $\lambda_2$ must be greater then $pq-2$.

Without loss of generality we assume that $\lambda_2>pq-2$-------------------(1).

Now since $p>1$ we have $p(q-1)-1<pq-2$----------(2).

> > From (1) and (2), $p(q-1)-1<pq-2<\lambda_2$-------------------(3)

We just need to show that $\lambda_1<p(q-1)-1$.

However I am stuck in showing that

> $\lambda_1<p(q-1)-1$.

Can someone help me to show this inequality?

Comment: $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=(3pq−p−q−2)$, $\lambda_1\times \lambda_2=(2p^2q^2−2p^2q−2pq^2+2pq−2p−2q+4)$  Try solving for $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Please do not delete answers after they have been answered. This discounts the effort of those who have answered your question and constitutes vandalism.

Comment: @robjohn;apologies,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^2-(3pq-p-q-2)x+2p^2q^2-2p^2q-2pq^2+2pq-2p-2q+4.$

Thus, should be $$f(p(q-1)-1)=(q-1)(-pq+3p+3)<0$$  and 
$$f(pq-2)=-p^2q-pq^2+6pq-4p-4q+4<0.$$
Can you end it now?

By the way, we need $p(q-3)>3,$ which gives that $q\geq5,$ otherwise the statement is wrong.

Comment: Yes I can end it. I only dont understand how to you got $(q−1)(−pq+3p+3)<0,−p^2q−pq^2+6pq−4p−4q+4<0$

Comment: @Math_Freak $f(x)=(x-\lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2),$ which says that for all $\lambda_1<x<\lambda_2$ we have $f(x)<0$.